# xaml layout file won't link to Strings in Resource.resw

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a simple hub app

the default template has this `HubPage.xaml`

[image]

since `x:Uid` the strings should be yet linked to `Resurces.resw` in `Strings` folder (if I have understod the documentation)

[image]

so I have created the folder for another language and edited both `Resurces.resw` files to show the name `Bla Bla Test` rather than default `"application name"`

unfortunately this doesn't work and header continues to show `"application name"` ignoring `Resurces.resw`

What is wrong?

**update:** following the suggestion of Romasz(see the comments) when I run the emulator is correctly shown the value of `Resurces.resw`...why in the preview this not happens

[image]

Comment: Have you set the default language in *package.appxmanifest* file?

Comment: yes I have set en-US

Comment: Have you tried to build it and run? You won't see the values from resources in the designer - you see those default values. As I've just tried the default template Hub App - seems to work.

Comment: Yes I have tried to buit and run ...i'm able to change the value only editing the xaml file but Resurces.resw are ignored

Comment: In fact, in template there should be: `HubSection1.Header` (not `HubSection1`) in *Resources.resw*.

Comment: I haven't understod where exactly have to write `HubSection1.Header`, could you give me a sample? I have taken the basic VisualStudio sample and changed the String values in Resurces.resw

Comment: I've modified a default sample app [here at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/HubAndResources). Basically in your resources file you have `HubSection1 -> SEZIONE1`, it should be `HubSection1.Header -> SEZIONE1`. `x:Uid` defines the name, but you should define in which property you put text - in this case *Header* (as I think it's a little bug in this template). Try to run the sample from GitHub.

Comment: thanks for the sample but I have opened your project and still get the same issue

Comment: update: when I run the emulator is correctly shown the value of Resurces.resw...why in the preview this not happens

Comment: AFAIK the designer (preview) doesn't show the values from resource, that's probably why there are some default ones.

Comment: Ok thanks... Microsoft must fix this thing as soon as possible. Now if you want, you can copy-paste what you have said in a standard answer, so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've tried with default template (Hub App), there seems to be a little mistake in *Resources.resw* file. Instead of `HubSection1 -> Section 1` there should be `HubSection1.Header -> Section 1` - `x:Uid` defines the name of an element, but in resources there should be added a path to property.

Nevertheless, from my experience and what I've tried, the designer preview won't show values from *Resources.resw* file. To see the effect you will have to build and run your project on emulator/devidce.